# How to load network drivers into InitramFs (Debian)

Tags: debian, networking, drivers, initramfs

As per `/usr/share/doc/dropbear-initramfs/README.initramfs` you have to include the drivers of (one of) your networking cards. It gives a script for getting all networking drivers in use:

```bash
while read m _; do 
/sbin/modinfo -F filename "$m"
done </proc/modules | sed -nr "s@^/lib/modules/\`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net(/.*)?/([^/]+)\.ko\$@\2@p"
```

I get four results:

```
ixgbe, mdio_devres, libphym mdio
```

I've determined through `lspci -v` that the network card that I want active in InitramFs uses `ixgbe`, but I think that maybe it is dependent on some of the other ones listed.

1. Do I need to include just ixgbe or some of the others?
2. How do I determine which of the others?
3. I need to specify them in "load order" in `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`, how do I determine this load order?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my analysis of the output of `update-initramfs -v -u` including a module in `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` will ensure its dependencies are included automatically.